# Multi region Lambda function to get the configuration from aws appconfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-app-config

We have a requirement wherein our AWS AppConfig is in US region and we have lambda function written using boto3 and it is created across all the aws regions.

Now, we are using below url to get the configuration from AWS Appconfig.

```
url = f'http://localhost:2772/applications/{app_config_app_name }/environments/{app_config_env_name}/configurations/{app_config_profile_name}'
```

Using above URL if we run the lambda function from US region then it works fine. But if we try to run the lambda function from another region let's say singapore region then it is failing as it is unable to get the configuration from aws appconfig.

So, what I understood here is using above URL it tries to get the appconfig details from the same aws region where the lambda function is running.

So, wanted to check if there is any other solution which I can implement to support multi region lambda function to get its configuration from the appconfig created in US region.

Note:- We don't want to create AWS AppConfig in all the regions.

Comment: Be aware that this will increase the cold start of your Lambda (assuming you are only reading the configuration once during Lambda instantiation) the further the region is away from the US geographically speaking. If the Lambda is not used for user-facing processes "on the critical path", this is fine. Otherwise, I would advice to replicate configs in all regions.

Comment: @Jens - Thanks for your feedback and yes we are aware about the situation and this configuration will not change and lambda will fetch the configuration from its local cache.